# Calling rnorm with a vector of means

Tags: r, vector, statistics, normal-distribution

When I call `rnorm` passing a single value as mean, it's obvious what happens: a value is generated from Normal(10,1).

```
y <- rnorm(20, mean=10, sd=1)
```

But, I see examples of a whole vector being passed to `rnorm` (or `rcauchy`, etc..); in this case, I am not sure what the R machinery really does. For example:

```
a = c(10,22,33,44,5,10,30,22,100,45,97)
y <- rnorm(a, mean=a, sd=1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The number of random numbers `rnorm` generates equals the length of a. From `?rnorm`:

> n: number of observations. If
>   ‘length(n) > 1’, the length is taken
>   to be the number required.

To see what is happening when `a` is passed to the mean argument, it's easier if we change the example:

```
a = c(0, 10, 100)
y = rnorm(a, mean=a, sd=1)
[1] -0.4853138  9.3630421 99.7536461
```

So we generate `length(a)` random numbers with mean `a[i]`.

Comment: Can we use rnorm(100) or something similar to create values only between 0 and 1? currently it gives values between (-1 to 1)

Answer (score 5):

a better example:

```
a <- c(0,10,100)
b <- c(2,4,6)
y <- rnorm(6,a,b)
y
```

result

```
[1]  -1.2261425  10.1596462 103.3857481  -0.7260817   7.0812499  97.8964131
```

as you can see, for the first and fourth element of ***y***, **rnorm** takes the first element of ***a*** as the ***mean*** and the first element of ***b*** as the ***sd***.

For the second and fifth element of ***y***, **rnorm** takes the second element of ***a*** as the ***mean*** and the second element of ***b*** as the ***sd***.

For the third and sixth element of ***y***, **rnorm** takes the third element of ***a*** as the ***mean*** and the third element of ***b*** as the ***sd***.

you can experiment with diferent number in the first argument of **rnorm** to see what is happening

For example, what is happening if you use 5 instead 6 as the first argument in calling **rnorm**?

Comment: it just obeys the recycling rules of R