# Simulation of forecast having lower and upper levels

Tags: r, simulation, forecasting, random

I am trying to simulate the forecast (rather than taking mean) using this code:

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame("lower" = c(-1, 0.5, 0), "upper" = c(0, 2, 4), "mean" = c(-0.5, 1.2, 2.5))
df$simulation <- rnorm(1, df$mean, (df$upper - df$lower) / 2 / 1.96)
df
#  lower upper mean simulation
#1  -1.0     0 -0.5 -0.6281103
#2   0.5     2  1.2 -0.6281103
#3   0.0     4  2.5 -0.6281103
```

I get same value in the simulation column.

However, if I provide the vector in the `n` parameter I get result that looks better:

```
df$simulation <- rnorm(nrow(df), df$mean, (df$upper - df$lower) / 2 / 1.96)
df
#  lower upper mean simulation
#1  -1.0     0 -0.5 -0.6281103
#2   0.5     2  1.2  1.2503308
#3   0.0     4  2.5  2.4194724
```

Is the later solution is the right way of doing this?

Comment: from a coding point of view, yes it seems OK. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3511841/3871924

Comment: Thanks. is it wrong from non-code point of view? )

Comment: i have no idea :-)